# What number should be the answer to this question?

Tags: riddle, steganography

Now that my first puzzle's done and gone it wont be so easy to solve the rest.
I've begun to write with reestablished rules.
If I've not got your attention I'll start trying harder.
So weigh the options and look closely,
It shouldn't be hard for you to tell me what number I'm thinking of...

Comment: I originally had the sentences separated like this @dcfyj, but I figured it would make finding the numbers too easy. Not that it slowed down @F1Krazy!

Comment: Feel free to roll back if you like.

Comment: No worries, it's already answered.

Comment: Not so difficult, but a well-conceived puzzle all the same.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Close examination of the text reveals

> hidden numbers:
>
>  Now that my first puzzle's d**one** and g**one** i**t wo**nt be so easy to solve the rest. I've begun to write wi**th ree**stablished rules. I**f I've** not got your attention I'll start trying harder. So w**eigh t**he options and look closely, It shouldn't be hard for you to tell me what number I'm thinking of...

These are

> **1 1 2 3 5 8** - the first six numbers of the Fibonacci sequence

So I believe you're thinking of

> the next number in the sequence: **13**

Comment: Well that was easy!

Comment: Can we upvote this until it has 21 votes? (why, you ask? ...no reason)

Comment: @QPaysTaxes here you go https://puu.sh/tU0co/2e118468cc.png

Comment: I noticed that the number of letters for each line increments by one line, except the last line unless you put the accepted answer in, which then fits the pattern.  In other words I found a completely meaningless pattern.